# How to pass the arguments to a batch file?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have requirement to run a set of *.sql files using batch file like this.

```
private void btn_Execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try {
    //Creating A batch file to execute the scripts using SQLPLUS....
    FileInfo fi5 = new FileInfo("c:/EMPSCRIPTS/execute.bat");
    StreamWriter sw2 = fi5.CreateText();
    sw2.WriteLine("@Echo Off \r \nsqlplus scotte/tiger@emp @\"c:/EMPSCRIPTS/RUNALL.sql\" \r \nEXIT ");
    sw2.Close();

    System.Diagnostics.Process proc; // Declare New Process
    proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatFilePath"].ToString()); // run test.bat from command line.
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatFilePath"].ToString();
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Insertion Completed");
  }

}
```

But I want to stop some files being executed unnecessarily. I found the option for passing the parameters. I want to give the parameters to the files staticly. Based on the users input that parameter has to execute. Could any one help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also, `"\r \n"` is wrong.  There shouldn't be a space there.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the values of StartInfo after the process has been started, which has no effect on the process.  [See the "Remarks" section here for more information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)

Create a new instance of [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx), set it up with what you need, then pass it into [the overload of Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) that takes an instance of this type.

In addition, once you change your code around, you can probably skip writing the command line to the batch file.  Your [executable filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) is `sqlplus` and your [arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) are `scotte/tiger@emp @\"c:/EMPSCRIPTS/RUNALL.sql\"`

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `Process.Start`.

You need to create a new `ProcessStartInfo` object, set all of its properties, then pass it to `Process.Start`.

Modifying the `StartInfo` of an already-running process, as your code is doing, has no effect.